# My single layer perceptron converges on the OR dataset, but not on the AND dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, perceptron

I am building my first single-layer perceptron network and I am training it to mimic the behavior of the simplest kind of logic gates (AND and OR) with two inputs.

The network consists of two input nodes and a bias. The delta-rule learning algorithm for single layer perceptron is used, with the tanh function as the activation function.

When trained on the AND dataset, the network should give an answer close to `1` when given an input `(1, 1)`, and 0 for any other input such as `(0, 1)`, `(1, 0)`, or `(1, 1)`. When trained on the OR dataset, it should return an answer close to `1` when given any input other than `(0, 0)`.

However it is exhibiting a behavior which I could not understand. It converges well (ie., error rates are pretty low - `0.01` or less) when I trained it on the OR dataset:

```
$ python nn.py
[0 0]: (actual result = [[0.00051257]]). (expected result from training set=0, error rate=[[-0.00051257]])
[0 1]: (actual result = [[0.98865851]]). (expected result from training set=1, error rate=[[0.01134149]])
[1 0]: (actual result = [[0.98865222]]). (expected result from training set=1, error rate=[[0.01134778]])
[1 1]: (actual result = [[0.99993485]]). (expected result from training set=1, error rate=[[6.51512784e-05]])
```

However, it does not converge well on the AND dataset:

```
$ python nn.py
[0 0]: (actual result = [[-0.28911014]]). (expected result from training set=0, error rate=[[0.28911014]])
[0 1]: (actual result = [[0.23984154]]). (expected result from training set=0, error rate=[[-0.23984154]])
[1 0]: (actual result = [[0.28911014]]). (expected result from training set=0, error rate=[[-0.28911014]])
[1 1]: (actual result = [[0.68570095]]). (expected result from training set=1, error rate=[[0.31429905]])
```

I've tried adjusting the `epoch` to various numbers between `500`-`10000` to no effect. And `eta` to anywhere between `0.1` to `1.0`.

Looking at the converge plot below, you'll see how the neural network is converging much better for the OR dataset than the AND dataset as depicted by the ever 'thinning' orange plot.
[image]

I thought OR and AND gates are the reverse of each other and if a network works on one, well, it should definitely work on the other. What am I missing here?

Here I have attached the source code of `nn.py`.

<del>NOTE: When you look you'll see that I have initialized the weight matrix to 1s instead of to some random values. This is simply because I want some determinism to help me troubleshoot. As I understand it, it should not affect the correctness of the algorithm (though it may make it slower to converge).</del>
The weight is now properly initialized to some random values, following @Dennis Soemers' suggestion. The problem still exists.

```
import numpy as np

def tanh(x):
    return (1.0 - np.exp(-2*x))/(1.0 + np.exp(-2*x))

def tanh_derivative(x):
    return (1 + tanh(x))*(1 - tanh(x))

# AND dataset
training_set = [
    (np.array([0, 0]), 0),
    (np.array([0, 1]), 0),
    (np.array([1, 0]), 0),
    (np.array([1, 1]), 1)
]

# # OR dataset
# training_set = [
#     (np.array([0, 0]), 0),
#     (np.array([0, 1]), 1),
#     (np.array([1, 0]), 1),
#     (np.array([1, 1]), 1)
# ]

weight = np.random.rand(3, 1)

# fit
eta = 0.2
epoch = 5000
for i in range(0, len(training_set)*epoch):
    input_, expected_output = training_set[np.random.randint(0, len(training_set))]
    input_with_bias = np.concatenate((input_, np.ones(1))).reshape(3, 1)
    sum_weights_of_input = np.dot(input_with_bias.T, weight)
    actual_output = tanh(sum_weights_of_input)
    error = expected_output - actual_output
    delta = np.multiply(eta, np.multiply(error, np.multiply(input_with_bias, tanh_derivative(sum_weights_of_input))))
    weight = weight + delta

# print
for input_, expected_output in training_set:
    input_with_bias = np.concatenate((input_, np.ones(1))).reshape(3, 1)
    actual_output = tanh(np.dot(input_with_bias.T, weight))
    error = expected_output - actual_output
    print("{}: (actual result = {}). (expected result from training set={}, error rate={})".format(input_, actual_output, expected_output, error))
```

Comment: an improvement would be updating your eta(decreasing) at the end of the loop. Also, this is a very trivial example so you probably wont need 5000 epochs when you end up with the right algorithm, should converge at most 20 epochs or so

Answer (score 4):

Apart from the note on random initialization of weights (which you have already addressed now, moved that point to the bottom of the answer), it is important to note that you are using `tanh` as activation, but you expect outputs close to `0` or `1`. `tanh` is much more suitable for cases where you expect outputs in `[-1, 1]`, rather than `[0, 1]`.

I suspect that, with your network's architecture, it is simply not possible to get outputs closer to the desired outputs for the AND problem than what you're already getting. Consider this plot of the `tanh` function:

[image]

Let `w0` denote the weight for the bias (always `1`), and `w1` and `w2` the weights for the first and second inputs `x1` and `x2`, respectively. Our output is always going to be `y = tanh(w0 + w1 x1 + w2 x2)`.

Let's first just consider the case where `x1 = x2 = 0`, where we want the output to be approximately `0`. In other words, we want to have `tanh(w0 + 0 + 0) ~= 0`. If you look at the image, this is only possible if our bias' weight `w0` is itself also approximately `0`.

Now, consider the cases where `x1 = 1` or `x2 = 1`, and the other input is `1`. Again, the desired output is `0`, and from the above we already know that we have to have `w0 ~=  0`. So, now we know that we want the following two things to be approximately true:

- `tanh(w1 x1) = 0`
- `tanh(w2 x2) = 0`

If we look at the image again, we see again that both of the points above can only be true if both of the weights `w1` and `w2` are approximately equal to `0`. So, now having considered only three out of the four possible inputs, we're already stuck wanting to have **all** of our weights roughly equal to `0`. If we want this, our output for the final input is doomed to also be roughly equal to `0`. So, to conclude, with the `tanh()` activation function and the specific architecture you chose for the network, it's impossible to get precisely the output values we want for the AND problem.

**Note:** The network you have is still able to "solve" the AND problem successfully if you take a slightly less strict notion of "solving". Note that, with the results you are getting, it is able to cleanly separate the different cases. It doesn't cleanly provide outputs very close to `0` or `1` as you want them, but you can easily come up with a threshold (such as `0.5`) and say "every output below this threshold is treated as `0`, every output above it is treated as `1`".

If you want outputs closer to precisely `0` and `1`, you could consider using the [sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) instead of `tanh`. It has a very similar shape, but generates outputs only in `[0, 1]` (precisely the output range you want), rather than `[-1, 1]`.

---

> NOTE: When you look you'll see that that I have initialised the weight matrix to 1s instead of to some random values. This is simply because I want some determinism to help me troubleshoot. As I understand it, it should not affect the correctness of the algorithm (though it may make it slower to converge)

This is indeed likely the (or at least a) cause of your problem. When all weights have the same initial value, you get symmetries that can no longer be broken. Some pairs of weights will always have the same starting value, same gradient, same error, and get updated in exactly the same (meaning they remain permanently identical). You can also see this reflected in your outputs and errors; note how there are some numbers that are nearly identical (in the case of AND problem, one being precisely the negative of the other).

You will want to use random initial weights, so that you break these symmetries from the beginning. If you want determinism, you can simply do this by using a fixed seed for your random number generator, so that you always get the same "random" initial weights.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I've tried them but the issue still persists.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback - I've tried that but it doesn't seem to be the cause of the issue. However, the difference between various activation function is still a very good insight for me as a newcomer. As for the real issue, I have just realized after plotting the error rates, that the network does not actually converge on the AND dataset.

Comment: @lolski I suspect that the lack of convergence is simply because, as I described, it is impossible for the given architecture + activation function to find a perfect solution. When you keep giving it examples one by one, it will always steer towards a "perfect solution" for the most recent training example, which will likely be a worse solution for the other examples, resulting in the bouncing / oscillating errors.

Comment: @lolski You could try giving the entire (mini)batch of all four input-output pairs at once instead of giving examples one-by-one. You can then do learning on the average of the four gradients rather than single gradients, and you can plot the average error over the four instances instead of always plotting the error for the single most recent instance. I suspect that average error should converge; not to `0` because no perfect solution is possible, but still converge to some constant average error.